# How can I turn off font-antialiasing only for gnome-terminal, but not for other applications?

Tags: linux, gnome, fonts, gnome-terminal

I'm running GNOME (gnome-session under xmonad). I want to turn off antialiasing (i.e. use monochrome mode) for fonts in gnome-terminal. But I want to retain antialiasing for other applications, like Firefox. Is this possible?

Antialiasing is great and almost necessary for using Firefox or Chrome. But it makes the fonts in gnome-terminal blurry at sizes around 12 or smaller.

Otherwise, I'll just have to use xterm, which seems not to anti-alias its fonts under any circumstances.

Comment: I have the same issue with xmonad.. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this actually works, but you could try to use .Xdefaults to configure this. Make a file named .Xdefaults in your home dir. Put in the following:

```
Xft*antialias: false
```

Effects everything!!! Just find the right name, and it should work.

Comment: That didn't work, sorry

Comment: Sorry, fixed it! And it works, checked!

Comment: Damit! That seemed to effect everything. But that file is the answer! read about it =)

Answer (score 1):

Why not try using a decent anti-aliased TrueType monotype font, a la [terminus](http://fractal.csie.org/~eric/wiki/Terminus_font)? It looks great at nearly any size. On Ubuntu/Debian the package is named xfonts-terminus.

Comment: It is not antialiased. Actually, with antialiasing (in GNOME 3) it looks uber-ugly.

Comment: Terminus at 8 looked good and not antialised in gnome-terminal for me. But now that Ubuntu 20.04 discarded X11 fonts (if I understand correctly), terminus at 8 in gnome-terminal is fuzzy too. Size 10 is not, and it looks fine att size 10 with zoom=0.85. Almost.

Answer (score 0):

As for I only want to use the courier new font size 10 in the terminal, here is how I finally made it. With this way, only courier new 10's antialias is disabled, which makes everything else is the same as before.

And you may get more information from [font configuration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Font_Configuration) and [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/32727/how-do-i-turn-off-font-pixel-antialiasing-only-in-terminal)

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <test name="family">
            <string>Courier New</string>
        </test>
        <test name="size" qual="any" compare="EQ">
             <double>10</double>
        </test>
        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I recently wanted to do the same (on Ubuntu 2004).

Create a file in the following directory (you may have to create the directory):

```
~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf
```

Add the contents of the file as follows. It will allow you to manipulate font behavior.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font">
        <test name="prgname" compare="contains">
            <string>gnome-terminal</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

### Explained

Everything inside the `match` elements tells the system how to find (match) and manipulate fonts. Note that in this example, we are **not** filtering based on any font properties (like family) - so it means we will apply this rule to **all fonts**.

```xml
<match target="font">
...
</match>
```

In order to limit the anti-alias toggle to only gnome-terminal, we will restrict it to any program that contains the string "gnome-terminal" as follows.

```xml
<test name="prgname" compare="contains">
    <string>gnome-terminal</string>
</test>
```

Lastly, we can how manipulate the `antialias` property for the matched font.

```xml
<edit name="antialias" mode="assign">
    <bool>false</bool>
</edit>
```

If you wanted to limit the antialiasing to a specific font, you could add something like this (inside the `match` elements):

```xml
<test name="family" qual="any" compare="eq">
    <string>CaskaydiaCove Nerd Font</string>
</test>
```