# Per-application font hinting and anti-aliasing in Gnome

Tags: gnome, fonts, gvim, anti-aliasing

How can I change font-hinting and ant-aliasing on a per-application basis for Gnome? I am specifically looking to enabled hinting for gvim without affecting my other applications. It seems like the answers would lie in some form of gtkrc file. My question is similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/130267/how-can-i-turn-off-font-antialiasing-only-for-gnome-terminal-but-not-for-other-a).

Answer (score 0):

IMVHO, it should be a matter of choosing a proper font and rendering mode.  I my setup I have gotten good results using [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) (11) and Subpixel smoothing (LCDs).  [Inconsolata](http://www.levien.com/type/myfonts/inconsolata.html) is a very good monospace font.